# Find, compute and justify the existence of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

FInd, justify and compute the following integral.

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int^2_1{x^{2-(\sin n x)/n}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

I don't know how to prove that this integral exists, and while computing it, would u substitution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). First, note that $2-\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\leq 3$ for any $n\geq 1$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and $x^y$ is increasing in $y$ for $x > 1$. Therefore, $x^{2-\sin(nx)/n}\leq x^3$ for $x\in (1, 2)$, and as $\lim_{n\to \infty} x^{2-\sin(nx)/n} = x^2$ for $x\geq 0$ and $x^3$ is integrable on $(1, 2)$, dominated convergence allows us to pass the limit into the integral as follows: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_1^2 x^{2-\sin(nx)/n}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_1^2 \lim_{n\to \infty} x^{2-\sin(nx)/n}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_1^2 x^2\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{7}{3}$$

Comment: Wonderful answer. That was succinct and got everything done.